# EventHandler containing generic type not appearing in Designer

Tags: c#, generics, designer, eventargs

I have a generic `EventArgs` class defined as:

```
public class GenericEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public GenericEventArgs(T value)
    {
        Data = value;
    }

    public T Data { get; private set; }
}
```

If I add an `event` of type `EventHandler<T>` to my `UserControl`, it will only appear in the Designer if I subclass my generic `EventArgs` type.

```
// this event will not appear in Designer
public event EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<String>> Event1;

// this event appears in Designer as expected
public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> Event2;
```

where `StringEventArgs` is defined as:

```
public class StringEventArgs : GenericEventArgs<String>
{
    public StringEventArgs(String value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the `[Browsable(true)]` attribute to the event, and marking the `EventArgs<T>` class as `Serializable` without success.

What could be causing this, and is there a workaround (other than subclassing) available?

I am using VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: The Winforms designer has very limited support for generics, it started at .NET 1.0.  It can handle an EventHandler<> okay but a generic of a generic is too much.  You'll have to accommodate it and give up your GenericEventArgs.

Comment: Thanks, thought this might be the case. Not the end of the world.